# Mobaxterm like ssh manager for linux

Tags: ssh

I am looking for a GUI program that has a file viewer on one side with download/upload functions when connected via ssh. Any suggestions for Linux desktop?

Comment: Software recommendations are off topic. You can ask on [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: @GeraldSchneider ok

Answer (score 0):

I've been a daily user of SecureCRT for many years and the few interactions I've had with VanDyke have been excellent.

Their [SecureFX client](https://www.vandyke.com/products/securefx/unix.html) might suit your needs; it's available standalone or bundled with SecureCRT.

You can get a free 30-day eval here: https://www.vandyke.com/

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but a free program will fit better to me.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't realised that MobaXterm was free.